# Grant ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION permission for testing using adb fails in Marshmallow

Tags: android, permissions, automated-tests

Here is the recipe of the problem:

1. Add mock location permission in debug manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>`
2. Install debug version of application in phone (in Gradle: `debug { debuggable true }`)
3. Try to give permission with adb: `adb shell pm grant com.myapp.name android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION`

The outcome of the command is:

> Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION is not a changeable permission type"

If I go to developer options on the phone and set `Setting >> Developer Option >> Select Mock location app` it works.

I need this for automated tests, so obviously the option of going to the phone settings is not valid because it's reset on every installation of the app, so I need the adb option to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution inside the Calabash fix for this same problem: 
https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/commit/b31be97953325383b9295ff52234a0121cc27e27

```
adb shell appops set com.myapp.name 58 allow
```

To do this automatically from gradle you can add the command to the install tasks:

```
def adb = android.getAdbExe().toString()
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name.startsWith('install')) {
        task.doLast {
            android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                "${adb} devices".execute().text.eachLine {
                    if (it.endsWith("device")) {
                        def device = it.split()[0]
                        println "Granting test permissions on device ${device}\n"
                        "${adb} shell appops set ${variant.applicationId} 58 allow".execute()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But you have to explictly call the install task before the connectedTest task, like:

```
gradlew installMyAppDebug connectedMyAppDebugAndroidTest
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use Test Butler plugin to manage test permissions among other things https://github.com/linkedin/test-butler

Example project where I configured and use Test Butler: https://github.com/sebaslogen/Blendletje/

```java
public class TestRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner {
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        TestButler.setup(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext());
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void finish(final int resultCode, final Bundle results) {
        TestButler.teardown(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext());
        super.finish(resultCode, results);
    }
}
```

```java
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    final Context targetContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
    TestButler.verifyAnimationsDisabled(targetContext);
}
```

You can see how it's installed automatically when running tests: https://github.com/sebaslogen/Blendletje/blob/master/app/build.gradle#L107